# Multi Page Banner Image Call on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a word-press banner rotator called Content slider on a page that's supposed to have 72 Banners And the banners are called as shown bellow. But that calls the whole banners at the same time.

```
<?php if(function_exists('wp_content_slider')) { wp_content_slider(); } ?>
```

It could also be called only on a specific page like show below

```
<?php
if(is_front_page())
{
if(function_exists('wp_content_slider')) { wp_content_slider(); }
}
?>
```

Is there a way to also call specific images on a specific page?

Comment: What do you mean by "call specific images"?

Comment: For Instance, Have three images display on the front page and then another different three on the about us page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not enough information about the function you are referring to in your post to give a definitive answer as to whether or not the function is capable of it as it stands.

There are two methods I would investigate if I had to come up with a solution.

- The least intrusive/most hackish method would be to wrap that function in an output buffer and modify the returned results prior to output.
- A better solution would be to look for/add a filter for the data generating the content.

Additionally, I would take whichever solution is implemented to filter the images and wrap that in an AJAX call.  This way you can load the page as is with a preloader in place and make AJAX calls to retrieve the next images.